# Memo test case update with validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am using multi chained select which has options in it. I have used Chosen.js to style my select and option tags.

The hover for option tags works. i.e. i am able to set a different background color when the option tags are hovered upon.  but i am not able to hover the select tag itself.

Does anyone know how to style this select eleement.

```
import FormFieldLabel from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/FormFieldLabel'
import FormFieldErrors from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/FormFieldErrors'
import MockStoreProvider from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/MockStoreProvider'
import { getString } from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/lib'

import Memo from '../Memo'
import FormInput from '../../../with-dirty-check/FormInput'

jest.mock('wf-dbd-react-ui/es/lib', () => ({
  getString: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => 'Optional'),
  globals: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    billpayBusinessUser: true
  }))
}))

describe('Memo Component', () => {
  let wrapper
  const coreState = {
    strings: {
      'optional': 'Optional'
    }
  }

  describe('when rendering', () => {

    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = mount(
        <MockStoreProvider digitalCoreState={coreState}>
          <Memo.WrappedComponent fieldId={'ImRequired'} getString={getString} defaultMemo="memo" />
        </MockStoreProvider>
      )
    })

    it('renders FormInput component', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(FormInput)).toHaveLength(1)
      expect(wrapper.find(FormInput).prop('initialValue')).toBe('memo')
      expect(wrapper.find(FormInput).prop('placeholder')).toBe('Optional')
    })

    it('renders FormFieldLabel component', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(FormFieldLabel)).toHaveLength(1)
    })

    it('renders FormFieldErrors component', () => {
      expect(wrapper.find(FormFieldErrors)).toHaveLength(1)
    })
  })
})
```

```
import FormInput from 'wf-dbd-react-ui/es/FormInput'

import withDirtyCheck from './withDirtyCheck'

export default withDirtyCheck(FormInput)
```

```
/*
Copyright (c) 2019 Wells Fargo. 455 Market St., San Francisco, CA 94105 All rights reserved.

This software is the confidential and proprietary information of Wells Fargo
bank. ('Confidential Information'). You shall not disclose such Confidential
Information and shall use it only in accordance with the terms of the license
agreement you entered into with WellsFargo.

Author: Ratul Bagchi

Description:
*/
import React from 'react'

const withDirtyCheck = Component => {
  class Wrapped extends React.Component {
    onChange = payload => {
      console.log('Dirty check')
      this.props.onChangeCallback && this.props.onChangeCallback(payload)
      return [payload.updates]
    }
    render() {
      return <Component {...this.props} onChangeCallback={this.onChange} />
    }
  }

  return Wrapped
}

export default withDirtyCheck
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

I've never used chosen.js, but had a quick look on (what I suspect is) the homepage.

If you inspect the 'into this' element (use Chrome, F12), you'll see `.chzn-container-single` has a `background-image` set to `-webkit-gradient`.

So changing the background `color` has no effect as it uses an image (which is shown over the top of the colour).

Add some css to your site.css (or look for this in chosen.css if you like to live dangerously):

```
.chzn-container-single
{
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom , #F00 0%, #0FF 50%)
}
```

change the colours as needed and change the chzn-container-single as needed

If this doesn't work, it may be because of precedence, so try adding it as a `style` directly to the element in the browser to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. You have to edit this style in case you want to style the select option background.

```
.chosen-single div b:hover {background: url('chosen-sprite1.png') no-repeat 0px 2px;}
.chosen-single span:hover {background-color:#538ECA;}
.chosen-single:hover {background-color:#538ECA; }
```

This is a workaround i found. It is the closest i could reach.